# How to handle transaction in Spring with weblogic and JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, weblogic

I am implementing an application in Spring with JPA and I am deploying it in weblogic server. I want to know how to handle transactions. For database configuration I configured persistence.xml where I declared the transaction type as JTA. In my persistence logic, while updating something, I am using this logic:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

but it throws an exception. If I don't commit the data is not updating in the database table. 
Even if I try with declaring @Transactional at method level it is not working.
Can any body please tell me how to handle transactions and if I am using them correctly or not.

Here are my files.

The DAO class:

```
  @Override
        @Transactional
        public void updateBpm(User user) {
            EntityManager entityManager=null;
            try{
             entityManager=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            String  query="update com_tt_bpm_batch set status = 'FAILED' where  seqNo="+user.getSeqNo();
            entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("table updated Successfully..");

                }
            catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e.getStackTrace());

            }

        }
```

Here is my spring configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    ">
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.tcs" /> 


        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
             <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/WEB-INF/META-INF/persistence.xml" /> 
             <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Mypersist" /> 
            <!--  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> -->
             <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
             <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
             <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property> 
        </bean>

      <bean id="baseTransactionProxy" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
      <props>
        <prop key="updateBpm">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="getforBpm">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
        <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
          <!--  <property name="database" value="oracle" /> -->
           <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
       </bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />



 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName"
      value="javax.transaction.TransactionManager"/>
  </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="Mypersist" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <jta-data-source>MCDataSource</jta-data-source>

    </persistence-unit>


</persistence>
```

Comment: You should inject the `EntityManager` but you are creating a new one, outside the visibility of Spring, rendering the `@Transactional` useless. When using JTA you aren't allowed to commit the transaction yourself, the container has to do this for you. I also hope that you aren't really using the old (and considered *deprecated* `TransactionalProxyFactoryBean`).

Comment: hi Deinum can you please tell me how to handle transaction in sping jdbc with weblogic sever. here i am using jndi.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating query:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
```

But you are not executing it: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate()

Comment: thank you very much for your reply it is working fine. and tell me one thing is my configuration is ok, i mean persistence.xml and spring config file

Comment: On the quick glance it looks OK, but see the comment on your question from @m-deinum - the `EntityManager` instance should be injected via `@PersistenceContext` and you should not commit the transactions yourself

Comment: hi can you please tell me how to handle transaction in case of spring jdbc, i mean no jpa,and hibernate in weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

I think better handle transactions on service layer (it's for situation when your service use several dao methods). And you should create your entity manager once, not for every dao method.

It's example how I handle transactions with jpa.

dao layer:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public String create(Brand brand) throws DaoException {
    try {
        entityManager.persist(brand);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);
    }
    return brand.getId();
}
```

example of service layer:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class BrandServiceImpl implements IBrandService {

    @Autowired
    private IBrandDao brandDao;

    @Override
    public TransportObject create(Brand brand) {
        TransportObject transportObject = null;
        try {
           // some code here
        } catch (DaoException e) {

        }
        return transportObject;
}
```

and configuration example:

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <value>package path</value>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: thank for your reply and can you provide persistence.xml file also

Comment: and i am using weblogic server to deploy,you configured  transaction regarding jpa not weblogic transaction. can you explain about it.

Comment: it is all configuration, you can use @PersistenceContext annotation  instead of persistence.xml file

Comment: I don't use weblogic server 
yes, I used spring transactions org.springframework.transaction.annotation;  transactions control service layer (and dao layer) and make rollback  in exception cases.